# Microsoft Bot in Azure but not working in Teams when used

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have hosted my ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) in Azure as an App Service through Visual Studio, which also created a new resource group, which it resides in.

This App service then created me a URL to use, which I suspect becomes my end point for my Bot eventually. My next step was to create a Bot Channel after going on this link here https://dev.botframework.com.

Steps taken:

- I registered a new Bot Channel with the endpoint being set to point
  to my app service (with /api/messages appended). During this process
  I was taken to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com in order to generate an
  App Id and a secret for my app.
- I then entered this information into the web.config file for my Bot.
- My next step was to go into MS Teams and create an application in "App Studio", which would have a Bot configured for it. The configuration for the Bot included the app id of my Bot in Azure, which I suspect is the relation between the 2 so that I can use my Bot in Teams.

However, when I try to use the Bot in Teams I get nothing back. There is no error thrown or any message displayed back in Teams. I'm not sure where I have gone wrong with this so does anyone have any ideas on what I could try?

Comment: Have you [uploaded your app package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-upload) from App Studio?

Comment: Did you add Microsoft Teams as channel for your bot?

Comment: Yes and yes. When testing this bot in Azure using the "Test in Web Chat" option on the "Bot channel registration" page it just returns "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue". I should add this bot worked when tested locally (using ngrok) before I updated my libraries in the "Reference" section to be the latest ones.

Comment: Please try re-creating your bot here: https://dev.botframework.com/bots/provision  ... Bots are now Azure resources in your subscription.  Bots created at https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new are provisioned differently, and need to be migrated.

Comment: Also, does the bot you've built implement a custom state client?  The default State Service has been deprecated: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/

Comment: Aha thats it! After implementing a custom state client using that link, my bot is now responding! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

New bots using the bot framework in Azure need to have their own custom state clients implemented. Use the following link to do this https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/. It should just be a minor change made to your "Global.asax.cs" file and "packages.config" file and that is all. To make additional use of the state client you can save data to it, which you can retrieve later on by using the instructions on this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0.